# Metodo ActionResult e async Utilizando FastMapper, Erro no TypeAdpter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net, async

Estou com o seguinte problema com o FastMapper.
No momento de implementar um ActionResult async quando utilizo o TypeAdapt o mesmo não consegue efetuar a conversão assincrona, alguém saberia informar em como fazer a conversão com o FastMapper?
Lembrando, quando faço a conversão na mão e ou sem async o mesmo funciona normalmente.
Código que apresenta o problema:

```
// GET: Credito/Details/5
public async Task<ActionResult> Details(int? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
    var creditoTabela = db.Creditos.FindAsync(id);

    CreditoViewModel creditoTela = await TypeAdapter.Adapt<CreditoModel, CreditoViewModel> (creditoTabela);


    if (creditoTela == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
    return View(creditoTela);
}
```

Imagem da validação e do erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mensagem do erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Sem a utilização do FastMapper funciona normalmente, meu problema é como utilizar o FastMapper com Async? Tenho que implementar alguma coisa na parte do Modelo para poder funcionar?

```
    // GET: Credito/Details/5
    public async Task<ActionResult> Details(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        var creditoTabela = db.Creditos.Find(id);

        CreditoViewModel creditoTela = new CreditoViewModel() {
            Codigo = creditoTabela.Codigo,
            Descricao = creditoTabela.Descricao,
            Nome = creditoTabela.Nome,
            Imagem = creditoTabela.Imagem
    };


        if (creditoTela == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(creditoTela);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Pela documentação da página inicial](https://fmapper.codeplex.com/), `Adapt` não é assíncrono.

Troque para:

```
// GET: Credito/Details/5
public async Task<ActionResult> Details(int? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
    var creditoTabela = await db.Creditos.FindAsync(id);

    CreditoViewModel creditoTela = TypeAdapter.Adapt<CreditoModel, CreditoViewModel> (creditoTabela);

    if (creditoTela == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
    return View(creditoTela);
}
```

Você já usa um método assíncrono dentro desta *Action*. O método do FastMapper não precisa ser também.

Comment: Havia pensado o mesmo no inicio porem persiste e ainda apresenta uma advertencia informando que o metodo sera sincrono mesmo a chamada async.

Comment: É mesmo. Esqueci do `await` em `var creditoTabela = await db.Creditos.FindAsync(id);`. Veja agora.

Comment: Rapaz tava obvio e não percebi, a consulta a base era asyn e nao havia setado o await nele, valeu e muito obrigado.